# UDP Socket programming - fork server on recev

Tags: sockets, udp

I want to implement a UDP socket server (using c under Linux). I want to avoid hanging client by forking a new process when the server receives a new message from the client. (i don wanna use threading)

The problem is that server keeps waiting (block on the recvfrom function), but when the client send the first message, the **server keeps forking MANY processes** (it looks like it is receiving the message more than one time or like the client is sending it many times, really i don know where the problem)

**Server:**

```
// socket file descriptor (socket descriptor)
int socket_fd;
// serverTCP and client addresses
struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
socklen_t sin_size;
int bytes_read;
char recv_data[1024];

// create the socket
if ((socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("UDP Server: ERROR while creating the socket.\n");
    exit(1);
}

// define the socket address associated with the created socket
// set the server address and port number

// set the binding of the serverUDP socket
printf("\nUDP Server: server socket binding...");
if (bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
    perror("UDP Server: ERROR while binding the socket.\n");
    exit(1);
}
printf("\nUDP Server: done binding.");

sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
// block and wait for connection request
int pid; // process ID for forking new serverUDP process
while (1) {
    printf("\nUDP Server: waiting for connection...");
    bytes_read = recvfrom(socket_fd, recv_data, 1023, 0,
            (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &sin_size);

    // a connection has been established
    recv_data[bytes_read] = '\0';
    printf("\nUDP Server: received -> %s", recv_data);
    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("UDP Server: ERROR while forking new process.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    // check if the process ID is zero
    if (pid == 0) {
        // we are now inside the new forked process
        char result[50];
        int len = sprintf(result, "%d", server_parse_command(recv_data));
        len = sendto(socket_fd, result, len, 0,
                (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, sin_size);
        close(socket_fd);
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

**Client:**

```
int socket_fd;
struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
struct hostent *host;
host = gethostbyname("127.0.0.1");

// create the socket
if ((socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("UDP Client: ERROR while creating the socket.\n");
    exit(1);
}
// define the socket address associated with the created socket
    // set the client address and port number

// send messages to the server socket
int count;
char buffer[128];
while (1) {
    socklen_t sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
    // read message to send to the server and set count to the length of the message

    count = sendto(socket_fd, buffer, count, 0,
            (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    if (count < 0) {
        perror("UDP Client: ERROR while writing message to server socket.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    bzero(buffer, 128);
    count = recvfrom(socket_fd, buffer, 127, 0,
            (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, &sin_size) ;

    if (count < 0) {
        perror("UDP Client: ERROR while reading response from server socket.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    buffer[count] = '\0';
    printf("\nUDP Client: received response -> %s", buffer);
    close(socket_fd);
}
```

Sorry for the long code.

Comment: Forking a new process every time you receive a UDP packet seems like extreme overkill... it would be very inefficient if your server receives a non-trivial number of packets per second.  It's also neither necessary nor sufficient to solve a hanging-client problem.  If your clients are hanging because they don't receive a reply packet in a timely manner, then you should address that problem on the client side (e.g. by using select() or poll() with a timeout, rather than just a blocking recv() call)

Answer (score 1):

(Answered by the OP in an edit. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I finally solved the problem, i will just put the solution i case someone faced it.
>
> In the server implementation and inside the `while(1)` loop. **check if the received bytes_read > 0** before doing anything, otherwise keep looping, so it will be something like this:

```
while (1) {
    printf("\nUDP Server: waiting for connection...");
    bytes_read = recvfrom(socket_fd, recv_data, 1023, 0,
            (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &sin_size);

    if (bytes_read > 0) {
                // a connection has been established
            recv_data[bytes_read] = '\0';
                printf("\nUDP Server: received -> %s", recv_data);
            pid = fork();

            if (pid < 0) {
                perror("UDP Server: ERROR while forking new process.\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            // check if the process ID is zero
            if (pid == 0) {
                // we are now inside the new forked process
                char result[50];
                int len = sprintf(result, "%d", server_parse_command(recv_data));
                len = sendto(socket_fd, result, len, 0,
                (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, sin_size);
                close(socket_fd);
                exit(0);
            }
    }
}
```